# How do I make the output of a View a particular Field?

Tags: 7, views

Right now my View is outputting a list of Nodes by their title. I've added a 'subtitle' field to these node's Content Type and I would like to use this as my outputted result instead.

I've gone to the 'Fields' section of my View but cannot find my newly added Content Field among the options there (have cleared cache and rebuilt registry).

Would anyone know how to achieve this?

(ps: why is it called 'Views'? Wouldn't 'Queries' be more accurate?)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? As for the name, Views started life as a contrib module (moved to core in 8) so the author can call it whatever they like I guess. If it were called Queries, it would be confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my Field was there in that list, but its name was different. It had adopted that name of a Paragraph it was used on. Apparently, if the Field is used in a Paragraph, the name you give it in that instance will be trump any other names you give it.

I don't know why this is or why this feature is useful.